# KnockoutJS - Select dropdown binding not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Im working on a project to build a CRUD system using knockout and getting and saving my data via AJAX. Been having issues binding the select dropdown. When I try to edit an incident I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

I created a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rqwku4kb/20/ to demonstrate the issue. I'm still working on the delete and add a new incident link so they are not working yet but im working on that seperately.

Here is the code that`s causing me issues at the moment.

```
self.ShowMeTheCurrentSelectedIncident = function(data) {
    self.currentIncident();
    self.chosen_composante.push([data.Composante]);
};
```

Would anyone have have any idea where the issue might be or be able to provide me some advice?

Comment: the code it is not legible, but if you change to this will work: `data.chosen_composante.push(data.Composante);`

Comment: It seems like my original jsfiddle didnt save correctly so it was missing a few things. But your line of code did clear the error. http://jsfiddle.net/rqwku4kb/27/ now my modal wont open correctly so im trying to figure that out now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method here is what's wrong:

```
self.ShowMeTheCurrentSelectedIncident = function(data) {
        self.currentIncident(); // (1)
        self.chosen_composante.push([data.Composante]); // (2)
    };
```

What this does:

(1) get the value of the observable `currentIncident` and then throw it away. It's always null and never set so this is doubly redundant. 
(2) Reference an undefined variable called `chosen_composante` which does not exist in `IncidentList`.

I could not fix this for you since I wasn't sure what values were to go where, but it should be enough to set you on the right track - you're confusing the properties of the IncidentList and Incident